# HttpModule to serve file on different server

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008

I would like to create an HttpModule that can serve a file that is on a different server.

Server A is publicly accessible and receives a request for file.txt. This file is on server B and Server A will serve it to the user. Server B is not publicly available.

What would be the highest performance method of accomplishing this with an HttpModule?

I could let Server A download the file from Server B and stream it back to the user. That would require a lot of resources from Server A to do that.

Another option might be that Server A will serve the file directly from an open fileshare to Server B. This would probably require less memory on Server A, but would still need the file to be streamed from Server B to Server A.

I hope there is some way that the request can be redirected to Server B and then the file can be returned directly from Server B to the client, possible facilitated by Server A.

I cannot simply redirect to Server B as it's not directly available to the end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably not invest in writing an HttpModule at all but instead I would use ARR ([Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing)) module to do the "proxying" for you in a way that is highly performant. You can also use its Caching functionality and that way if some files are "hot" they can be downloaded directly by the "front-end" server without hitting the back-end server. Using its cached will be the fastest option and since it can be pretty smart about caching it will be also one of the pain-less ways.

It is optimized to handle thousands of requests per second and does that in an async way that let it scale to huge numbers. Used in many content-delivery-network-type situations so you can count on it being really fast.

Comment: That's actually a great solution, but I just need to stay within the confines of an HttpModule ... :(